# Java: passing queue as a method argument?

Tags: java, methods, queue, priority-queue

I need to create `Event` class and `Venue` class.

In `Venue` class, I need to put priority queue. I need to write a method which removes and displays an event from the queue, as well as showing some simple statistics: average of people on every event etc.

I am stuck on the first point - a method that will remove and show this event. Is it possible to pass the whole queue as an argument to a method? - I tried to do it but it doesn't seem to work. - (display method in `Event` class).

```
public class Event {

    private String name;
    private int time;
    private int numberOfParticipants;

    public Event(String name, int time, int numberOfParticipants) {
        this.name = name;
        this.time = time;
        this.numberOfParticipants = numberOfParticipants;
    }

   /**Getters and setters omitted**/

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Wydarzenie{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", time=" + time +
                ", numberOfParticipants=" + numberOfParticipants +
                '}';
    }

    public void display(PriorityQueue<Event> e){
        while (!e.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println(e.remove());
        }
    }
}
```

Venue Class:

```
public class Venue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         PriorityQueue<Event> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparing(Event::getTime));
         pq.add(new Event("stand up", 90, 200));
         pq.add(new Event("rock concert", 120, 150));
         pq.add(new Event("theatre play", 60, 120));
         pq.add(new Event("street performance", 70, 80));
         pq.add(new Event("movie", 100, 55));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you can pass a collection as an argument to a method. What problem are you seeing when you try it?

Comment: Yes. You can pass any collection in the method. Few other things...I believe you should have queue only in the Venue class. You can add methods in the Venue class to display it and add events and other things. In the main, you can call display(pq); Also..I'm not sure removing each item to display is appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some changes to the venue class.

```
class Venue {
    PriorityQueue<Event> pq = new PriorityQueue<Event>(Comparator.comparing(Event::getTime));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Venue v = new Venue();
        v.addEvents();
        v.display(v.pq);
    }

    private void addEvents() {
        pq.add(new Event("stand up", 90, 200));
        pq.add(new Event("rock concert", 120, 150));
        pq.add(new Event("theatre play", 60, 120));
        pq.add(new Event("street performance", 70, 80));
        pq.add(new Event("movie", 100, 55));
    }

    private void display(PriorityQueue<Event> e) {
        while (!e.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(e.remove());
        }
    }
}
```

The queue is at the class level so each Venue can have its own queue. The main method just calls other methods but ideally should be placed in a different class. The display will be called on Venue instance and you can do your statistics in that method while removing each item from the queue.